# Нужна помощь: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, java-8

Есть проблема в коде, которую я не могу никак найти. Вроде все правильно, много форумов обсмотрел, но никак не пойму. Надеюсь на вашу помощь!)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class task_4_4 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] a = new int[20];
      int maxr = 20;
      int minr = -20;
      Random rand = new Random();
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         a[i] = 0 + rand.nextInt((maxr - minr) + 0) + minr;
         System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
      }
      int min = a[0];
      int imin = 0;
      int max = a[0];
      int imax = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         if (a[i] < min) {
            min = a[i];
            imin = i;
         }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         if (a[i] > max) {
            max = a[i];
            imax = i;
         }
      }
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Наименьший элемент: " + min + " его индекс: " + imin);
      System.out.println("Максимальный элемент: " + max + " его индекс: " + imax);
      int m = a[max];
      a[max] = a[min]; // Ошибка заключается здесь
      a[min] = m; 
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: ошибка в том, что вы обращаетесь к массиву , указывая в качестве индекса не индекс, а значение.   int m = a[imax];  a[imax] = a[imin];  a[imin] = m;

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: не за что. у вас в коде это далеко не самая большая проблема. сейчас сделаю чай и добавлю ответ,  думаю, будет полезно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Максимальный элемент это `max`, а его индекс это `imax`. Аналогично с минимумом.
Ошибка не только в указанной строке, но и во всех трёх строках:

```
int m = a[max];
a[max] = a[min];
a[min] = m;
```

Вы обращаетесь к элементу массива не по нужному индексу. Правильно будет:

```
int m = a[imax];
a[imax] = a[imin];
a[imin] = m;
```

Comment: Максимальный элемент массива может превышать его размер. Тогда происходит ошибка выхода за границу массива.

Comment: То же и с минимальным значением. Оно может быть отрицательным и тогда обращение к этому элементу также вызовет ошибку выхода за границу массива

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Очень глупая ошибка. Выручили!)

Answer (score 1):

Старайтесь как можно раньше начать использовать ООП вместо процедурной парадигмы. Выбирайтесь из метода main(). Главная задача - читаемость кода! Для этого для начала помните всего несколько простых правил: 1)осмысленное именование переменных, соблюдение конвенции об именовании; 2)чтение множества простейших (коротких) методов на много понятнее, чем чтение одного большого метода (принцип "разделяй и властвуй") хотя бы просто потому, что у метода есть осмысленное имя , что в сочетании с простейшим кодом дает быстрое понимание о том, как он работает и что он делает; 3) статика в большей части случаев - зло (почему - поймете со временем); 4)что бы вам не говорили, код написанный в ООП является самым читаемым и простым для понимания.

Я сознательно не пытался сделать класс универсальным и использовать интерфейсы, чтобы не запутывать вас лишний раз.

Предлагаю дополнительно разобрать такое решение. В нашей задаче нам необходимо выполнять над целочисленным массивом какие-либо дополнительные операции (которых нет из коробки у массива). Тогда давайте сделаем класс-обертку для массива, который будет хранить массив,а методы нашего класса будут выполнять все необходимые задачи. Добавим 2 конструктора : первый  будет принимать готовый массив, а второй - параметры для того, чтобы сгенерировать массив с рандомными числами. Мы знаем нашу задачу, поэтому найти индексы  максимального и минимального значение мы можем сразу (сами значения нам хранить не надо, ведь у массивов временная сложность доступа элементу по индексу О(1)). теперь вся информация, необходимая нам, подготовлена. Остается добавит методы для получения индексов и значений макс. и мин. элементов, а также метод , меняющий их местами, и метод вывода массива в консоль. Вот и все. Теперь вы можете использовать класс-обретку неограниченное количество раз, создавая экземпляры класса, мало того, вы можете добавлять новые методы, оптимизировать их выполнение (например, замена местами максимального и минимального элементов в нашей реализации больше не требует итераций, а их поиск при инициализации выполняется в один проход, вместе с тем вы можете использовать ленивую инициализацию, выполняя поиск макс. и мин. элементов при обращении к соответствующим методам и т.д.). Как видите, даже в таком простом примере можно получит ряд преимуществ при использовании такого подхода. Можете задавать вопросы, если они появятся.

```
public class IntArrayWrapper {

    private final int [] array;
    private int minIndex, maxIndex;

    public IntArrayWrapper(int [] array) {
        this.array = array;
        findMinMaxIndex();
    }

    public IntArrayWrapper(int size, int minr, int maxr) {
        this(new java.util.Random().ints(size, minr, maxr).toArray());
    }

    private void findMinMaxIndex() {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < array[minIndex]) minIndex = i;
            if (array[i] > array[maxIndex]) maxIndex = i;
        }
    }

    public void replaceMaxMin() {
        int m = array[maxIndex];
        array[maxIndex] = array[minIndex];
        array[minIndex] = m;

        m = minIndex;
        minIndex = maxIndex;
        maxIndex = m;
    }

    public int getMinIndex() {
        return minIndex;
    }

    public int getMaxIndex() {
        return maxIndex;
    }

    public int getMinValue() {
        return array[minIndex];
    }

    public int getMaxValue() {
        return array[maxIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return java.util.Arrays.toString(array);
    }

}


public class task_4_4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IntArrayWrapper wrapper = new IntArrayWrapper(20, -20, 20);
        System.out.println(wrapper.toString());
        System.out.println("Наименьший элемент: " + wrapper.getMinValue() + " его индекс: " + wrapper.getMinIndex());
        System.out.println("Максимальный элемент: " + wrapper.getMaxValue() + " его индекс: " + wrapper.getMaxIndex());

        wrapper.replaceMaxMin();
        System.out.println("************************************************");

        System.out.println(wrapper.toString());
        System.out.println("Наименьший элемент: " + wrapper.getMinValue() + " его индекс: " + wrapper.getMinIndex());
        System.out.println("Максимальный элемент: " + wrapper.getMaxValue() + " его индекс: " + wrapper.getMaxIndex());

    }

}
```