# Ошибка "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3"

Tags: java

Нужно сформировать одномерный массив, состоящий из произведения целочисленных элементов, располагающихся в четных строках матрицы X (n x m). Я вроде сделала, но выходит ошибка "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3". Подскажите в чем проблема?

```
 package Pr2;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class pr5 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            double[][] x;
            double []  z;
            int N,M,K;
            double P;
            int newn;
            Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("N = ");
            N = inp.nextInt();
            System.out.print("M = ");
            M = inp.nextInt();

            z = new double[N];
            x = new double[N][M]; // N-число строк M-число столбцов
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                    System.out.print("x(" + i + "," + j + ")=");
                    x[i][j] = inp.nextDouble();
                }
            }
            inp.close();

            //вывод матрицы в виде таблицы
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.printf("%6.2f", x[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            //произведения четных строк матрицы
            P = 1;
            newn = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<M; i= i+2) { //четные строки
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                    if (!(x[i][j] % 1 == 0)) { // если целочисленные, то считается произведение
                        P = P * x[i][j];
                        z[newn] = P;
                        newn++;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { //выводим новый массив
                System.out.printf("Массив: x(%d) = %1.2f\n", i, z[newn]);
            }
            if (newn == 0) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: M и N не путайте

Comment: переделала, но все равно выходит ошибка(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в коде это далеко не единственная ошибка. Читайте мой ответ по этому вопросу (все замечания касаются и вашего кода). [Нужна помощь: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1137983/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception?noredirect=1#comment1968130_1137983)

Результаты таковы:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pr5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[][] sourceArray = inputArray();

        //вывод матрицы в виде таблицы
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sourceArray[i].length; j++) 
                System.out.printf("%6.2f", sourceArray[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
        }

        double [] resultArray = calculate(sourceArray);
        //выводим новый массив
        for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) { 
            System.out.printf("Массив: x(%d) = %1.2f\n", i, resultArray[i]);
        }

    }

    private static double[][] inputArray() {
        double[][] sourceArray;
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Rows = ");
            int rows = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Columns = ");
            int column = scanner.nextInt();
            sourceArray = new double[rows][column];
            for (int i = 0; i < sourceArray.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < sourceArray[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print("x(" + i + "," + j + ")=");
                    sourceArray[i][j] = scanner.nextDouble();
                }
            }
        }
        return sourceArray;
    }

    //произведения четных строк матрицы
    public static double[] calculate(double[][] array) {
        double [] result = new double [array.length/2+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 2) { //четные строки
            double increase = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                if ((array[i][j] % 1 == 0)) increase *= array[i][j];
            }
            result[i/2] = increase;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

А раз у нас отдельный метод отвечает за расчеты и создание результирующего массива, мы можем написать юнит тест для отладки

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

```
public class Pr5Test {
    @Test
    public void testCalculate() {
        System.out.println("calculate");
        double[][] x = {{2,3.5,5},{1,3,8},{4,7,9}};
        double[] expResult = {10D, 252D};
        double[] result = Pr5.calculate(x);
        assertArrayEquals(expResult, result, 0.0001);
    }    
}
```

Я оставил ваши методы статическими, но это не отменяет того, о чем я говорил в указанном ответе.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: не за что, удачи вам

Answer (score 0):

После "//произведения четных строк матрицы" перепутаны M и N

Код

```
  z[newn] = P;
  newn++;
```

нужно вынести из внутреннего цикла, и вообще newn не понадобится.

"Целочисленность" инвертирована была.

```
for (int i = 0; i<N; i= i+2) { //четные строки
    z[i] = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        if ((x[i][j] % 1 == 0)) {
                z[i] *= x[i][j];
                }
            }
        }



for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { //выводим новый массив
            System.out.printf("Массив: x(%d) = %1.2f\n", i, z[i]);
        }
```

Comment: переделала как вы сказали, все равно выходит ошибка Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
 at Pr2.pr5.main(pr5.java:45)

Comment: вынесла из цикла вообще, теперь неправильно выводится массив
Массив: x(0) = 0,00
Массив: x(1) = 0,00 Почему-то не выводится произведение в виде массива

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка  при шагании  i+2 на нечётных, нужно остановить цикл при M-1

Comment: то есть нужно просто исправить "for (int i = 0; i<M; i= i+2) {"  эту строчку на "for (int i = 0; М-1; i= i+2) {  "??

Comment: Мне если не изменяет воображение то да

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) { //выводим новый массив
            System.out.printf("Массив: x(%d) = %1.2f\n", i, z[newn]);
        }
        if (newn == 0) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка");
        }
```

Измените в конце вашего кода цикл